# Select rows from two tables in sql

Tags: sql, join, table-relationships

I am having three tables which has primary keys and references. I need to select the rows in below way. Please any one help me.

Table: **Class** (`ClassId -> primarykey`)

```
ClassId  ClassTitle
--------------------
1        First  
2        Second
3        Third
```

Table: **Department**(`DeptId -> primarykey`)

```
DeptId   DeptName
-------------------
1        science
2        maths
3        general knowledge
```

Table: **ClassAndDepartment**

```
ClassId  DeptId(ClassId-> foreign key of class and DeptId->foreign key of Department)
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        3
```

Now I need to select the rows where the value exists in the table `Class` but does not exist in `ClassAndDepartment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from Class c where ClassId not in (select distinct ClassId from ClassAndDepartment)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from class c 
where classid not in (select classid from classanddepartment)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve this is using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Class C
LEFT JOIN ClassAndDepartment CandD ON C.ClassId = CandD.ClassId
WHERE CandD.DeptId IS NULL
```

Avoiding `NOT IN` will usually improve performance.